# How can I merge two data sets with a custom function that applies a rule to non-common columns?

Tags: r, function, date, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames of different sizes, but I am running into difficulties because of the panel structure of the data.

Consider the example below where 'toy.left' is a panel of three variables: a coordinate ('coord'), and a name ('name') assigned to that coordinate in a particular month ('month'). Next, consider 'toy.right,' which is comprised of four variables: a name ('name'), the start of that name's tenure for the assignment ('tenure.start') to that coordinate, and the end of their tenure for the assignment ('tenure.end') to that coordinate.

```
toy.left <- tribble(~month, ~coord, ~name, 
"2000-01-01", 1301, "Alpha", 
"2000-03-01", 1301, "Beta", 
"2000-06-01", 1302, "Charlie", 
"2000-09-01", 1303, "Delta", 
"2000-12-01", 1303, "Epsilon")

toy.right <- tribble(~name, ~coord, ~tenure.start, ~tenure.end, 
"Alpha", 1301, "2000-02-01", "2000-04-01", 
"Beta", 1301, "1999-11-01", "2000-04-01", 
"Charlie", 1302,  "2000-04-01", "2000-07-01", 
"Delta", 1303, "2000-08-01", "2000-10-01", 
"Epsilon", 1303, "2000-11-01", "2001-01-01", 
"Delta", 1303, "2002-01-01", "2004-01-01")
```

I would like to merge these two data sets, but there are rules that make it difficult with merge() in dplyr. For example, I cannot simply use inner_join() and merge by 'name' and 'coord' because this violates the panel structure of the data. If I do this, the tenure of an individual does not overlap with the month of the observation (first, see Rows 1 & 2, which should be inverted; second, see Rows 4 & 5 where merge() duplicates the month observation, but should only include Row 4).

```
toy.left %>% 
  inner_join(toy.right, by = c("name", "coord"))

*Output*

month       coord   name   tenure.start tenure.end 
2000-01-01  1301    Alpha   2000-02-01  2000-04-01
2000-03-01  1301    Beta    1999-11-01  2000-04-01
2000-06-01  1302    Charlie 2000-04-01  2000-07-01
2000-09-01  1303    Delta   2000-08-01  2000-10-01
2000-09-01  1303    Delta   2002-01-01  2004-01-01
2000-12-01  1303    Epsilon 2000-11-01  2001-01-01
```

To solve this problem, I could merge the data by 'name,' 'coord,' ***and*** 'month,' but I would need to condition merging by 'month' on whether or not the date falls between 'tenure.start' and 'tenure.end.' After searching around, I could not find a way to apply a custom rule to merge() in dplyr.

I understand that a custom function or loop might be the best way to approach this, but I am not sure where to begin. Additionally, the original data set has more than 1.5 million observations, which may generate further issues.

I welcome your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(All this after converting `month` and `tenure.*` to `Date`-class.)

### fuzzyjoin

```r
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(
  toy.left, toy.right,
  by=c("name", "coord", month="tenure.start", month="tenure.end"), 
  match_fun=list(`==`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`))
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
#   month      coord.x name.x  name.y  coord.y tenure.start tenure.end
#   <date>       <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <date>       <date>    
# 1 2000-03-01    1301 Beta    Beta       1301 1999-11-01   2000-04-01
# 2 2000-06-01    1302 Charlie Charlie    1302 2000-04-01   2000-07-01
# 3 2000-09-01    1303 Delta   Delta      1303 2000-08-01   2000-10-01
# 4 2000-12-01    1303 Epsilon Epsilon    1303 2000-11-01   2001-01-01
```

### sqldf

```r
sqldf::sqldf(
  "select tl.name, tl.coord, tl.month, tr.[tenure.start], tr.[tenure.end]
   from [toy.left] tl
     inner join [toy.right] tr on tl.name=tr.name and tl.coord=tr.coord
       and tl.month between tr.[tenure.start] and tr.[tenure.end]")
#      name coord      month tenure.start tenure.end
# 1    Beta  1301 2000-03-01   1999-11-01 2000-04-01
# 2 Charlie  1302 2000-06-01   2000-04-01 2000-07-01
# 3   Delta  1303 2000-09-01   2000-08-01 2000-10-01
# 4 Epsilon  1303 2000-12-01   2000-11-01 2001-01-01
```

(I use `[tenure.start]` with the bracket-notation to differentiate between the table identifier `tl` and the column name `tenure.start`, where in SQL dots in the column names usually indicate `schema.tablename.columnname`-like nomenclature.)

### data.table

This does left-joins, not the other types. To identify which should be removed due to doing left instead of inner, I'll add a column to `toy.left`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(toy.left)
setDT(toy.right)
toy.left[, val := 2]
toy.left[toy.right, on = .(name, coord, month >= tenure.start, month <= tenure.end)][ !is.na(val),]
#         month coord    name   val    month.1
#        <Date> <num>  <char> <num>     <Date>
# 1: 1999-11-01  1301    Beta     2 2000-04-01
# 2: 2000-04-01  1302 Charlie     2 2000-07-01
# 3: 2000-08-01  1303   Delta     2 2000-10-01
# 4: 2000-11-01  1303 Epsilon     2 2001-01-01
```

`data.table` has its way of renaming columns, so be aware of it. When I'm not certain I know how the naming is going to end up, I often copy the columns around so that it's always clear ... but part of the reason I'm doing that is laziness in learning exactly how it determines the resulting names.